# MySQL service stuck at starting after increasing 'innodb_log_file_size'

Tags: mysql, eset

Good day everyone,
We are trying to install the 'ESET Enterprise Inspector' on a server, which requires mysql. we installed MySQL Server 8.0
in the [requirement page](https://help.eset.com/eei/1.2.1/en-US/index.html?mysql_installation.html)  it says we have to use these parameters:

[image: requirements]

But when we try to start the mysql service, the progress bar goes to end and it says "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" and it is stuck in starting status. the eset installer doesn't continue to install if we haven't used those parameters.
The server has 32G of ram and we use `innodb_buffer_pool_size=26G` and `innodb_log_file_size=13G`

Does anyone know why the service doesn't start? I can upload the my.ini if needed.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the [my.ini file](https://pastebin.com/bMc2X6MS)

Comment: Start MySQl service directly from the command line. Then show console log and error log. my.ini is not interesting now.

Comment: Have you tried to ask on vendor's [forum](https://forum.eset.com/forum/82-eset-enterprise-inspector-edr/)?

Comment: @Akina I've edited the post

Comment: @ge0rdi they don't even answer to tickets properly. I'm really disappointed with the product.

Comment: Edit my.ini, set `datadir` parameter in `[mysqld]` section to correct value `datadir=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data`. Check that the account MySQL service is starting from have full rights in this folder. Then try to start service again. And do not forget to check that `--defaults-file` parameter in service command line is pointed to correct my.ini file...

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry, the my.ini is already correct. I tried to run mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" from cmd and the it looks like something is happening but it doesn't write anything, the courser is just blinking.

Comment: Check MySQL service command line - it is to be `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80`. If not, edit it, and then try to start service.

Comment: @Akina It's already correct

Comment: Remove (or save and remove) error logs (*.err files in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data folder). Start MySQL service via Control panel. If not started then look/show newly created error log.

Comment: @Akina I did that and the file is now empty.

Comment: I.e. you open Control panel - Services, select MySQL80 and press Start... Progressor runs, and after few seconds you get the message that service cannot start, is it? Tell more, I cannot see your monitor...

Comment: @Akina exactly that, the progress bar takes longer like 2 minutes to complete and then gives the error. I will edit my.ini in the post for you.

Comment: Find `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\D11W19EEI01.err`. Look its content for lines relative to last start attempt. Does they exist?

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the answers man, but I think our conversation is going nowhere. I think the problem is on our part not mysql, since literally nobody else in the internet has this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is actually starting.   When you change the log file size or if the files have been removed they have to be resized.   I ran into this as well and thought it wasn't starting.  Then I opened the error log in notepad++ and noticed that it was incrementing the rebuild of the log file.   Once the rebuild of the log files was done MySQL proceeded to start.   The next time you stop and start it will start normally.

Comment: I've given it a day and still it didn't start

Comment: I was using MySQL 5.6 so it may be different with MySQL 8.0.   Mine was set to 2.0 GB and it took about 10 minutes to start.   If you check the .err file (Mine was under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data) I saw entries like the following:  2019-09-25 08:18:06 7272 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile101 size to 2048 MB
InnoDB: Progress in MB: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000
2019-09-25 08:22:06 7272 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 2048 MB

Comment: Yeah, I'll downgrade to 5.6 and try again